# How do I get rid of the small line that appears in-between offsets when using array?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm new to blender and was following along a tutorial but when I got to using the array tool on my model I noticed that mine was different to the video. When I use array with relative offset I can notice a small gap or line in-between each offset. It may not seem like a big thing but once I add a simple deform to get the shape I want it becomes a big problem. I feel like I followed the tutorial almost perfectly but seeing as it has no voice over its possible I made a mistake somewhere. I've added the images of the gaps below. If you have any ideas please let me know.

[image] [image]

[image]

[youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aC0GE9TeKGc&t=655s&ab_channel=CGSpace)

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: there is no modifier in your blend file....

Comment: New one has array on it if thats what you mean. Sorry I'm complete nooby.

Comment: can you please post the blend file of your "end result" -> the circle? and a link to the tutorial might help too. It is important that your objects have applied scale/rotation. you can do this with ctrl-a.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you need to go back a step and fix the *Array*. It should be 'Relative' offset, by '1' in X, and 'Merge' should be checked, so the array elements become continuous. But before you do that, you have to remove the faces at the element ends, that coincide where they join, otherwise there will be internal faces in the array. There will be no need to apply the array, you can leave the modifier live.

After doing that, and *Simple Deform > Bending* your array, there may still be a join visible where its ends meet at 360 degrees. You can get rid of that with a *Weld* modifier.

It may be worth going into the object's *Data* tab > *Normals* panel, to give the whole object an 'Autosmooth', set to about 45 degrees.

Your .blend had the Array applied, so I couldn't fix that. I repaired the mesh instead. But really, you should go back. It's better to keep your modifiers alive as long as possible, for flexibility.

[image]